# Query on a model field? Is it possible in models.py?

Tags: python, django

I have a model called `StudentProfile`:

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    class_advisor = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    year = models.OneToOneField(YearLevel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    section = models.OneToOneField(Section, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

what I want to happen is, `class_advisor` to only return and accpet `User` with `is_teacher = True`.

by the way here's my `User` model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        max_length=254,
        unique=True,
        verbose_name='Email Address',
        blank=True
    )
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Student')
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Administrator')
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Teacher')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Staff')
    is_registrar = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Registrar')
```

Comment: I saw same question twice authored by same user, please be specific to question. Your question should describe the problem and you should show some least of you efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, however at the moment, something is wrong with your modeling. You should make `class_advisor` a `ForeignKey` to the *user* model. Imagine that you store the username (or whatever unique attribute of that user) in your model. If later that teacher changes that username, then it will refer to a non-existing user, or later to a different user that picked the username.

You can set the [**`limit_choices_to=...`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='studentprofile')
    class_advisor = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), limit_choices_to=Q(is_teacher=True), related_name='students')
    year = models.OneToOneField(YearLevel, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    section = models.OneToOneField(Section, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

If you use forms, etc. It will limit the options to `User`s that are teachers, and do validation on this.

It is better to use [**`get_user_model()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) here to refer to your user model, since if you later alter it, the `ForeignKey` (and `OneToOneField` will refer to the new model).

Comment: hi sir thanks for your help, but i got an error ```ERRORS:
<class 'accounts.admin.StudentProfileInline'>: (admin.E202) 'student_dashboard.StudentProfile' has more than one ForeignKey to 'accounts.User'.
student_dashboard.StudentProfile.class_advisor: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'StudentProfile.class_advisor' clashes with reverse query name for 'StudentProfile.user'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'StudentProfile.class_advisor' or 'StudentProfile.user'.```

Comment: @newbieprogrammer: yes, you need to add extra `related_name`s

Comment: oh ok so when i added the `related_name` argument I caught another error ```OperationalError at /admin/student_dashboard/studentprofile/
no such column: student_dashboard_studentprofile.class_advisor_id``` i really dont know what to do at this moment thanks for your help sir

Comment: should i make another model for this?

Comment: @newbieprogrammer: you will need to make migrations and migrate. This is not really an error, you just modified your models.

Comment: thanks man! it worked! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`StudentProfile.objects.filter(user__is_teacher=True)`

Comment: ok, so where im gonna put it? Should it be like this?  `class_advisor = StudentProfile.objects.filter(user__is_teacher=True)` ?

Comment: You could query it in your view.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem's answer worked for me. Thank you anyway. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
StudentProfile.objects.filter(user__is_teacher=True).values('class_advisor')
```

Comment: hi sir, sorry I'm really new to django, so, should it be like this: `class_advisor = StudentProfile.objects.filter(user__is_teacher=True).values('class_advisor')` ?

Comment: @newbieprogrammer you wont get single class_advisor, result will be many advisors.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem's answer worked for me. Thank you anyway. I really appreciate it!